# How to alert sum?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function add(x,y)
{
  alert("sum is " + x+y);
}
```

When I call it with numbers, it doesn't add. So calling

```
add(1,2)
```

alerts

```
sum is 12
```

and not

```
sum is 3
```

like it should. Why? How can I alert the sum?

Comment: That code concatenates String + number then + number.  You need to wrap the addition with parentheses.

Comment: either perform the sum before printing, or put parentheses around the sum: "sum is " + (x + y)

Comment: that should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

By starting your expression as a string (`"The sum is..."`), JavaScript will evaluate the entirety of the expression *as a string*. Adding two strings together simply combines ("concatenates") them.

You can group `(x + y)` to cause it to be evaluated first/separately, similar to how order of operations might work in mathematics.

(For more information: [Arithmetic operators in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition_()))

```js
function add(x, y) {
  alert("sum is " + (x + y));
}

add(5,2);
```

As I mentioned earlier, the expression is evaluated as a string because it *starts* with a string. But what if we started it with the addition instead?

```js
function add(x, y) {
  alert(x + y + " is the sum");
}

add(5, 2);
```

Or possibly the best approach would be to simply use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
function add(x, y) {
  alert(`The sum is ${x+y}`);
}

add(5, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a string comes before your numbers in the following line: `alert("sum is " + x+y);` - this will cause JavaScript to treat each item as a string that you want concatenated, as opposed to added. You can remedy that by simply doing the addition before the `alert` and storing in a variable. Something like this:

```js
function add(x, y) {
  var sum = x + y;
  alert("sum is " + sum);
}

add(5, 10);
```

Comment: you can also do alert("sum is " + (x + y)), no need for a variable

Comment: @MatthewDoyle Yes you could. Achieving this using a variable is not a worse approach as some people prefer to be more explicit - just a matter of preference.